# Thermal spring. Gas and water characterization

Tags: geology, water, geothermal-heat

I am interested in assessing a thermal spring in the Ecuadorian Andes. However I have no experience in these type of geological features and I am not sure how to proceed. The spring is located over volcanic deposits: breccias, ashes and piroclastic deposits from mid - late Pleistocene (according to the geological map). The aim is to verify if this spring (water and gas) can be used in some practical application.

The spring emits also a gas (unknown at this point) aside from water. The gas seems to be toxic since some people died last year, but only during certain hours during the night (during the day, people use this spring with no problems).

Can you recommend some bibliography to start with? in reference to thermal emissions characterization, water characterization and if possible modeling of these kind of systems. If some similar case is known I will highly appreciate this information.

Comment: You question is a bit wide opened. Can you narrow the possible use down? e.g. - Do you want to use it for a mineral bath, geothermal power, or drinking water?

Comment: I would like to explore if there is a chance to take advantage of the gas emission, so the first thing which came to my mind was to characterize the gas. Nowadays the water is used by a community for ritual purposes, however, some people died last year (another reason to characterize the gas). So, in this context, as a natural resource I think I might need to know some details about the system and if possible to model it, in order to draw some conclusion with regard to its functioning in general terms.

Comment: There are reports of carbon dioxide emissions causing deaths. I'd not suspect hydrogen sulfide since it has a very noticeable stink. I'd also suspect that the spring emits whatever gas constantly. Carbon dioxide is heavier than air and will collect in low spots. A wind breeze would keep the concentration from reaching dangerous levels. The wind is usually lower at night.

Comment: Do you know of some value for gas emission rate of these kind of sources, I have searched but I cannot find a value which can be useful to start with a dispersion model or similar.